Looking backwards to navigate forwards
We often have questions here about objects moving at relativistic speeds through real space and one issue that always comes up is particle interactions at those speeds. This creates a bow shock of plasma that builds up in front of a solid object moving that fast through even the relatively thin interstellar medium. This blinds most modes of forward observation and traditional "point and shoot" navigation using anything except, possibly, neutrino sources as targets.
For the purposes of this question I'm going to make the very large assumption that we can protect an object moving at relativistic speeds from the impact damage we might expect them to accrue on their travels. This does nothing to stop the particle bow shock from forming and blinding most sensors, in fact a particle deflection system probably makes the plasma cloud problem worse.
What I'm interested in is whether a vehicle that cannot see anything ahead of it could use backward facing celestial navigation to bring it to a target in a fixed orbit?
In the case of automated weapons assume modern auto celestial fixing technology such as that used by commercial satellites for station keeping. If you feel the answer is different for a human pilot differentiate accordingly; said pilot would have access to an equally sophisticated automated system but you may have a scenario under which they are better off without it. Further assume that the target destination is in a fixed orbit, such as that of a planet or natural satellite and thus it's motions are easily predicted.

Orbital speed is very very much lower than relativistic speed. Going into any kind of orbit requires slowing down to orbital speed, and all problems disappear.

@AlexP Yes if you want to go into orbit it gives you some margin for error, some, but that first tag is Weapons not Spaceships and the question is worded "bring it to a target" not into orbit, if you want to hit the target you don't want to slow down. Even if you do want to make orbit ports and targets, especially in the outer system, can be far enough apart that a low enough speed to use sensors could mean years of undilated travel time, and being really off target when you slow down enough to hopefully see your destination out front could be a death sentence.

I love this idea
This has so many possibilities for story telling! The short answer is this: Yes, you can do that... to a degree. To quote from the movie The Hunt for Red October:

[Kamarov] Give me a stopwatch and a map, and I'll fly the Alps in a plane with no windows.
[Yuri] If the map is accurate enough.

Weakness #1: Ignoring for a moment the absolute vast nature of space, if what you're trying to avoid is the rogue planet that's in your path then backward-facing celestial navigation (BFCN) buys you nothing other than the momentary burst of radiation when you and the planet evaporate. It would be spectacular! But that's one weakness of the system — you only know what's reported to exist on your "map" (star charts, database...) and can't know that there's something that requires a change of plans.
Weakness #2: You didn't exactly ask this, but for completeness, could one use BFCN during combat? I believe the answer is "no" as you need to know where something should be to use BFCN in the first place. When it comes to something that can choose to change direction BFCN is a serious liability. Also, see that rogue planet problem, above. You really don't know where your victim target is in the first place.
Weakness #3: But! Another weakness is precision.  It will come into play with distance or, better still, exploration where "should be" isn't as definitively known as a regularly visited system. In fact, you could have a lot of fun with the "practical reality" that no computer system is infinitely capable nor any storage system infinitely large, meaning you can't really store every object and all the math behind its motion in relation to everything else. (Well, you could... but I'm not a fan of godlike computers. They take all the fun out of things.)
Weakness #4: Also, what's your point of reference? Everything's moving, even the galaxy. We could theoretically make the assumption that the galaxy isn't moving fast enough to affect navigation, but that might fail the science-based tag. I once asked a question about using a far-distant star's spectroscopy for navigation using scifi hyperspace jumps. The point of the question is that as you move through space in anything but "real time" (call that "Earth standard time" and ignore a lot of math) where things "should be" might be a challenge to know. In the worst case where "jumps" are instantaneous (I know, not part of your question) the light you're approaching is getting younger (and the star's location is moving) and the light you're navigating by is getting older (and that location is moving, too). That's a whomping ton of calculation — fun!
Why is this all important? Because of your statement,  Further assume that the target destination is in a fixed orbit, such as that of a planet or natural satellite and thus it's motions are easily predicted. That very much depends on the precision of your "maps" because planets are in a fixed orbit around their sun only from the perspective of their sun. From the point of view of an interstellar traveler, they're doing this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQJez9iiS7Y
(Hey, Mods! Why aren't we one of the sites that allows YouTube videos to be embedded into posts?)
Conclusion

Is it scientifically believable? Yes.
Does it have enough problems to make for an interesting story? Oh, yeah.


fwiu, the closer to light speed something travels, the more the whole visible sky condenses and contracts forward of the moving object; at that point there is nothing behind to look at.

@user721108 You're absolutely correct, but mathematically it's believed to be impossible to accelerate entirely to the speed of light - and the OP didn't indicate their limits. I'm assuming a limit, but to be honest, what you're pointing out is yet another example of the dependency on precision.

Plausible and possible. Some details need special care.
Terminology
I don't know if  "Celestial fixing technology" would be the correct term. I know that "Astrogation" (Astro-Navigation) is used in Sci-Fi literature often to describe such technology, but I do not know if this is a real thing at NASA for example. Also, terms like "star tracker" exist, but might be just fictional (or were colloquially used by astronauts during Apollo).
Astro Inertial Navigation Systems
There are two instances I know of, where such or at least similar technology was used:

Apollo-Mission's PGNCS
SR-71 Blackbird's ANS - nicknamed "R2-D2"

Both had in common using a gyroscope (or more of them, for redundancy and to be able to compare values) to preserve a (more or less) stable reference direction vector. Problem is, that the gyroscope needs to be recalibrated from time to time.
The Apollo Missions had Ground Control which provided update vectors obtained by observing stars or other reference points via the Deep Space telescope Network.
The SR-71's device was able to track stars which had to be pre-programmed. It was then possible to obtain stable navigation data by triangulating with two observed stars. It was mentioned that the SR-71 was able to track those stars even in daylight. Keep in mind that back in the days, they had no GPS available yet (at least not fully), so having accurate positional data was crucial.
In fact, the direction in which you look to see the stars, does not matter, as long as you are able to recognize the reference points (star formations or whatever). The SR-71 device was built-in at the top, checking for stars above it, for example.
With a bit of fictional sugar, to solve the calibration problem, a spaceship would not even need to see stars at all (during flight). Rather the needs for odometry have to be met. Meaning, exact measurements of starting point (by stars), time and speed (problematic with FTL).
--> Given suitably advanced technology and star data available, such a device would not be a problem to be built. It would be plausible that it exists.
Star Data
Imagine today's positional data of stars available, this would be too limited to provide a starship travelling to other systems. Keep in mind: All this data was recorded with earth as reference point. This is okay in our solar system or maybe near galactic vicinity, because apparently existing star formations would not change that much.
If you are able to "pass by solar-systems" in your spaceship, you can imagine that your view angle might change in a way that stars overlap each other or even apparently swap places. The star database has to be huge and the computer has to be able to consider coordinate transformations to some advanced level, I would assume.
Speed of light
Assuming you want to conduct interstellar-travel and not only visit planets from the solar-system. You would face some other difficulties, though.
As long as you are below c it should be plausible to navigate by "visual indicators". If you need FTL-drives in your plot, it would be implausible to navigate by optical means. Since you are faster than light, light from the stars, especially those which are behind you, could not reach you anymore.
Auto Pilot Navigation
Assuming today's level of resolution of telescopes, you would probably not be able to see or "aim for" a planet in another star-system. Think of current resolutions when trying to find Exoplanets.
You might be able to aim for a star though. Meaning, an Auto-Pilot might steer you up to some point near that star, but then other means have to be used to check for the planet's position and compute a rendevouz course for orbiting and landing. The starship could have a built-in telescope for that, for example. Could also be fully automated.
I would deem it rather impossible, that the computer can accurately aim for a planet without some secondary navigational step. Even if all data like revolving times, inclination, incoming angle etc. etc. were known, simulations based on that would be highly inaccurate.  Fast forwarding a simulation would multiply an even small deviation to an extent were it matters if you end up on the planet or on one of it's moons by accident...
Human Pilot
I associate this case with some kind of "short term navigation" / manual override and the need for turning the whole ship in various directions and maybe roll even. Like, for example a combat situation or some other quick maneuver. Also landing.
The pilot will most certainly not be able to quickly recognize any star to know were he is headed given enough "random" turns. Computer assistance seems absolutely necessary to be plausible. The computer could rely on the mentioned devices of course and give the pilot some visual aids to a HUD etc.
It seems plausible that the landing phase makes manual intervention inevitable. It is like in our airplanes. Starting and Landing still is done manually. Only the "cruising" in between can be handled by an autopilot, which more or less just needs to hold course.
Weapon systems
This is dependent on characteristics of the weapon. To give some ideas:

Turrets would be able to use the star-data from the computer to orient themselves.
Rockets/Missiles and Fighters would have the same restrictions as described in terms of "auto pilot" flight and available navigational data.
Laser weapons are questionable in combination with FTL.
Given high enough speed, the ship would not be able to do quick maneuvers. Only smaller fighters would be able. Because a large ship with high velocity has a high inertia/momentum. It would need the same energy to break it down to zero as was invested to bring it up to speed. This can easily mean several million kilometers until standstill. Think of a train, or a container ship, if you want an analogy of plausible "dexterity" of a large ship.
Since the large ship could only drop off fighters and continue its flight, those fighters would not be able to get back to the ship again. So they are not a viable option also.


Who's suggesting going faster than light? This question is specifically about going really fast below the speed of light; relativistic speeds, i.e. notable percentages of c, in real space.

You can just skip that section, @Ash. It is optional. I intentionally separated that as an own section. The only reference to it is in combination with the lasers, which can also be left out, if not applicable.
